# System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a binary file, using memorystream and filestream and a struct, with the code below:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
byte[] buffer = null;
long numBytes = new FileInfo(filename1).Length;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
mStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
mStream.Position = 0;
GameSaved newdata = (GameSaved)formatter.Deserialize(mStream);
mStream.Close();
fs.Close();
fs.Dispose();
mStream.Dispose();
```

The `GameSaved` struct looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
struct GameSaved
{
    public int Num_Of_Saved_Game;
    public string[] Name_Of_Saved_Game;
}
```

But the code throws an error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Edit: This is how I save my `GameSaved` struct:

```
buffer = null;
formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
mStream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(mStream, newdata);
buffer = mStream.ToArray();
mStream.Close();
filename = "name.sav";
curFile = @"c:\C#\Try_To_Save_MS\Try_To_Save_MS\bin\Debug\name.sav";

if (File.Exists(curFile))
    File.Delete(curFile);

fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
fs.Write(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
fs.Dispose();
mStream.Dispose();
```

Could anyone please show me the way to solve the problems?

Best Regards

Comment: what line is throwing exception? `GameSaved newdata = (GameSaved)`?

Comment: It's the line "GameSaved newdata = (GameSaved)formatter.Deserialize(mStream);"

Comment: Probably something is broken in the part where you Serialize the GameSaved instance. Could you add that code also?

Comment: Yes, please wait a moment

Comment: And please start using using(). All those .Close()/.Dispose() are making me extremely worried about rest of your application.

Comment: I've just tried to do as what you said, Steve, but it threw the same exception. Anyway, thank you for your help. Besides, is there anywhere else that could be the problem?

Comment: Did you remove all the stuff related to saving the buffer? They are no more needed after the Serialize call

Comment: Yes I did, I changed everything according to what you told, but it still threw the same exception at the same line

Comment: I have rewritten all of your code in the answer below. I tested it and it works as expected

Comment: But does it matter if the Serialize and Deserialize stay in 2 different forms?

Comment: As what I tried, serializing in 1 form and deserializing in the other one seems to make the code throw the exception

Comment: When you say you're serializing/deserializing in "two forms" , do you mean two separate Winforms classes? If so, does that also mean that you are defining the structure twice?

Comment: Yes, so it makes the problem, right?

Comment: It is a pretty standard mishap when you use BinaryFormatter.  It is pretty smart and knows exactly which GameSaved declaration was used.  Not just its namespace name and type name and what members it has, also what assembly it came from.  Kaboom when you don't use the *exact* same assembly when you read it back.  So one basic mistake you could make is re-declaring the struct.  Realistically you have to put it in a class library that you use both in the code that writes the file as well as the code that reads it.

Comment: Thank you so much, so what could I do in order to fix the problem?

Comment: Don't redeclare the structure (remove one of the `struct GameSaved{...}`) , move the other one out of the form class so it's not nested (directly in the namespace) OR make the nested one `public` and then use that type everywhere

Comment: Finally, I've solved the problem. Thank you all for your precious attention and helpful guides!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the BinaryFormatter.Serialize method to serialize your object. In your code you write a buffer but probably this don't do the same thing

A sample of serialization of your data could written in this way

```
GameSaved reloaded = new GameSaved();
void Main()
{
    GameSaved game = new GameSaved();
    game.Num_Of_Saved_Game = 2;
    game.Name_Of_Saved_Game = new string[] {"game1", "game2"};

    Serialize(@"e:\temp\serialize.bin", game);
    Deserialize(@"e:\temp\serialize.bin");

    Console.WriteLine("Games:" + reloaded.Num_Of_Saved_Game);
    foreach(string s in reloaded.Name_Of_Saved_Game)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}

void Deserialize(string filename1)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        reloaded = (GameSaved)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
void Serialize(string filename1, GameSaved game)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        formatter.Serialize(fs, game);

}
[Serializable]
struct GameSaved
{
    public int Num_Of_Saved_Game;
    public string[] Name_Of_Saved_Game;
}
```